# Where can I find the exe for Version=1.0.61025 of Ajax tool kit ?? (ASP net 2.0)

Tags: asp.net, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I need to install System.Web.Extensions.dll on my server machine ?

I am after the exe install file

(I have the files in a old machine C:\Program Files\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET 2.0 AJAX Extensions\v1.0.61025  just not the registry keys)

I Have this Error: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a871acff-7f9a-448f-a70d-e543d078c748/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-systemwebextensions-version10610250-cultureneutral?forum=aspdotnetajax

Version=1.0.61025.0, is for MS VS 2005 Asp net 2.0

They say the old versions are at CODEPLEX which is gone. Seee here: http://www.ajaxtoolkit.net

.."If you are using .NET Framework 2.0 and Visual Studio 2005 then you should use the earlier Toolkit version 1.0.20229 at CodePlex. "....

Where can I find the exe for Version=1.0.61025 of Ajax tool kit ??

Comment: As long as I remember Ajax toolkit did not needed to be installed on the server. Just copy dlls of that dinosaur to the bin folder and it should work.

Comment: Worse yet, the ajaxtoolkit has and had ZERO ZERO to do with that folder, and the .dll called system.web.extensions were NEVER part of the aj toolkit. That part of asp.net had things to allow one to use and make ajax calls on a page - not really at all what the aj toolkit does (the aj toolkit was sample code that makes ajax calls, but it NEVER provided the ajax framwork at all). see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2267048/what-is-system-web-extensions-for